# Setting a default value in Vagrantfile if env. variable not set

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I'm trying to do something like the following to set a default value if an environment variable is not set:

```
config.vm.box = ENV['VAGRANT_DEV_BOX'] || "ubuntu/xenial64"
```

Which causes the following error:

```
/opt/vagrant/embedded/lib/ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/version.rb:208:in `initialize': Malformed version number string debian-VAGRANTSLASH-jessie64 (ArgumentError)
```

The `VAGRANT_DEV_BOX` variable hasn't been set at this point. Confirmed like so:

```
server   echo $VAGRANT_DEV_BOX

server
```

Is it possible to do this in Ruby and/or Vagrantfile?

Comment: It looks like `config.vm.box` expects the version and `ENV['VAGRANT_DEV_BOX']` contains this `"debian-VAGRANTSLASH-jessie64"`. It has nothing to do with `|| "ubuntu/xenial64"` part since it never gets executed.

Comment: `ENV['VAGRANT_DEV_BOX']` is null at this point as it hasn't been set. `config.vm.box` expects a string such as `ubuntu/xenial64`. Edited question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is thanks to `double-p` on #vagrant, freenode:

> `<double-p>` you cannot just inline ruby.. put this above vagrant-configure, like:

```
port = ENV["HOST_PORT"] || 8080

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: port
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "vagrant/provision.sh"
end
```